# I am getting exception invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array

Tags: base64

when I use `Convert.FromBase64String(myString))` where `myString` length is `827744`, I get exception 'Invalid length for a base-64 char array'

myString is encoded zip file using notepad and I add "`=`" to make it multiple of 4.

Can anyone help here ?

Thanks in advance.

I want to read into those file content and use c# zip archive to read through memory stream,
MemoryStream(convert.FromBase64String(myString)). I am getting exception.

Comment: ...what do you mean by "encoded zip file using notepad"?

Comment: `827744` is almost an entire megabyte - you should not be using `String` values, let alone Base64 encoding, for values that long...